# I ran lsof - i -P in search of an answer for an undocumented service running on port 8081/tcp. What does the following mean?

Tags: network

This is the information garnered from running lsof -i -P while searching for an undocumented service running on port 8081. What does this all mean and is it something I should worry about?

com.apple 761 cindypennmcbain    5u  IPv4 0x40f90735ba18742d      0t0  TCP macbook-air.lan:49614->151.101.1.69:443 (ESTABLISHED)

com.apple 761 cindypennmcbain   18u  IPv4 0x40f90735ba10542d      0t0  TCP macbook-air.lan:49615->dfw06s48-in-f106.1e100.net:443 (ESTABLISHED)

com.apple 761 cindypennmcbain   19u  IPv4 0x40f90735bbd3742d      0t0  TCP macbook-air.lan:49616->151.101.193.69:443 (ESTABLISHED)

com.apple 761 cindypennmcbain   23u  IPv4 0x40f90735c47f1a4d      0t0  TCP macbook-air.lan:49618->104.16.25.34:443 (ESTABLISHED)

com.apple 761 cindypennmcbain   27u  IPv4 0x40f90735c43658ed      0t0  TCP macbook-air.lan:49620->dfw28s23-in-f1.1e100.net:443 (ESTABLISHED)

com.apple 761 cindypennmcbain   30u  IPv4 0x40f90735c4368a4d      0t0  TCP macbook-air.lan:49624->dfw06s48-in-f2.1e100.net:443 (ESTABLISHED)

com.apple 761 cindypennmcbain   31u  IPv4 0x40f90735c47efcad      0t0  TCP macbook-air.lan:49623->dfw25s34-in-f14.1e100.net:443 (ESTABLISHED)

com.apple 761 cindypennmcbain   37u  IPv4 0x40f90735c47f106d      0t0  TCP macbook-air.lan:49628->dfw06s48-in-f2.1e100.net:443 (ESTABLISHED)

com.apple 761 cindypennmcbain   38u  IPv4 0x40f90735c436806d      0t0  TCP macbook-air.lan:49629->dfw25s17-in-f2.1e100.net:443 (ESTABLISHED)

com.apple 761 cindypennmcbain   39u  IPv4 0x40f90735c436768d      0t0  TCP macbook-air.lan:49631->oq-in-f155.1e100.net:443 (ESTABLISHED)

com.apple 761 cindypennmcbain   41u  IPv4 0x40f90735ba100f0d      0t0  TCP macbook-air.lan:49632->server-13-249-25-68.iah50.r.cloudfront.net:443 (ESTABLISHED)

com.apple 761 cindypennmcbain   43u  IPv4 0x40f90735b9c7b42d      0t0  TCP macbook-air.lan:49633->dfw25s25-in-f1.1e100.net:443 (ESTABLISHED)

com.apple 761 cindypennmcbain   44u  IPv4 0x40f90735c469606d      0t0  TCP macbook-air.lan:49637->dfw25s34-in-f3.1e100.net:443 (ESTABLISHED)

com.apple 761 cindypennmcbain   45u  IPv4 0x40f90735bbd3568d      0t0  TCP macbook-air.lan:49635->dfw28s02-in-f4.1e100.net:443 (ESTABLISHED)

com.apple 761 cindypennmcbain   47u  IPv4 0x40f90735c4694cad      0t0  TCP macbook-air.lan:49638->e1.ycpi.vip.cha.yahoo.com:443 (ESTABLISHED)

com.apple 761 cindypennmcbain   48u  IPv4 0x40f90735c436942d      0t0  TCP macbook-air.lan:49640->server-99-86-100-55.iah50.r.cloudfront.net:443 (ESTABLISHED)

com.apple 761 cindypennmcbain   50u  IPv4 0x40f90735bb9022cd      0t0  TCP macbook-air.lan:49642->dfw25s25-in-f6.1e100.net:443 (ESTABLISHED)

com.apple 761 cindypennmcbain   54u  IPv4 0x40f90735bb904a4d      0t0  TCP macbook-air.lan:49645->dfw28s05-in-f2.1e100.net:443 (ESTABLISHED)

com.apple 761 cindypennmcbain   55u  IPv4 0x40f90735bb9018ed      0t0  TCP macbook-air.lan:49646->dfw06s49-in-f2.1e100.net:443 (ESTABLISHED)

com.apple 761 cindypennmcbain   58u  IPv4 0x40f90735bb97806d      0t0  TCP macbook-air.lan:49650->dfw28s05-in-f2.1e100.net:443 (ESTABLISHED)

com.apple 761 cindypennmcbain   62u  IPv4 0x40f90735bb9762cd      0t0  TCP macbook-air.lan:49653->104.16.133.229:443 (ESTABLISHED)

cindypennmcbain@macbook-air ~ %

Comment: It looks like all the line breaks have been removed from the output. Please [edit] and paste the exact output into code formatting so it’s readable.

Comment: This looks like this question : https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/393580/237687